# -[NSString componentsSeparatedByString:] leak

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory-management

I have the following code:

```
NSString *indexText = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
if (indexText==nil) {
    [indexText release];
    indexText = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
}
[data release];
NSAutoreleasePool *innerPool = [NSAutoreleasePool new];
NSArray *packageList = [indexText componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n\n"]; //if commented out, there's no leak
[indexText release];
[innerPool drain];
```

I'm performing a `componentsSeparatedByString:` on `indexText`, but I leak quite a bit of memory, despite that fact that `packageList` is autoreleased (proven by the fact that the code crashes if I try to release it again). When I comment out the line with `componentsSeparatedByString:`, the leak disappears.

By the way, I'm viewing memory usage in Activity Monitor whilst running iPhone Simulator; Instruments doesn't detect a leak. Is the leak just an illusion, a peculiarity of the Simulator?

Comment: By the way (unrelated to the question): if (indexText==nil) [indexText release] does not make any sense. If an initializer returns nil, it will have deallocated the object - you don't need to release anything. And really, you couldn't even send it this message because you don't get a pointer to the object you want to release, since it's nil (0x0).

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. I was thinking that since I was calling `[NSString alloc]`, I'd have to deallocate it; thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no way that memory could have really leaked, `componentsSeperatedByString:` returns an autoreleased `NSArray`.

Trust Instruments when it comes to these things.

Comment: That's what I'm inclined to believe; so the memory usage shown in Activity Monitor isn't representative of the actual memory requirement of my application?

Comment: "There is no way that memory could have really leaked", well, there is, e.g. if there's no autoreleasepool in place. If you don't call `NSApplicationMain` or `UIApplicationMain`, there is no autoreleasepool on the main thread unless you create one, just as there is no runloop running on the main thread and also no GCD main queue. Also don't forget, a leak is only if you lose reference to an object. If an object created is never released, yet it still could be released, that is not a leak (instruments won't report it as one), still that object hogs on your  memory.